# Eclipse Java ADT errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

When I run this code:

```
package com.example.topliga;

public class Update extends AutomaticUpdaterActivity {
    private Object context;

    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        String path = "http://192.168.1.20/android/TopLiga.apk";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("YourApp", "Well that didn't work out so well...");
            Log.e("YourApp", e.getMessage());
        }
        return path;
    }

    private void publishProgress(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String path) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive" );
        Log.d("Lofting", "About to install new .apk");
        ((Activity) this.context).startActivity(i);
    }
}

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.example.updater.AutomaticUpdaterActivity;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

    @SuppressLint("ParserError")
    public class TopLigaActivity extends ListActivity {

        static final String URL = "http://minesemhamachi.no-ip.org/android/usersdata.xml";
        static final String KEY_ITEM = "mydata"; // nodo pai
        static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        static final String KEY_username = "Username";
        static final String KEY_password = "Password";

        XMLParser parser;

        @SuppressLint({ "ParserError", "NewApi" })
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    parser = new XMLParser();
                    new DownloadXml().execute(URL);
                } 
        }

        private void setListView(String xml) {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // Obter elemento (DOM)
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); 

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
            // Iteração sobre todos os nodos <item>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // Criação de HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // Adição de cada nodo filho ao HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_username, parser.getValue(e, KEY_username));
                map.put(KEY_password, parser.getValue(e, KEY_password));

                // adição da HashList ao ArrayList
                menuItems.add(map);
            }

            // Adição dos menuItems ao ListView
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { KEY_username, KEY_password }, new int[] {
                            R.id.name, R.id.score });

            setListAdapter(adapter);

        }


        private class DownloadXml extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {           
                return  parser.getXmlFromUrl(urls[0]);            
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                setListView(result);
           }

        }
    }
```

These errors happen:

Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)    TopLigaActivity.java /TopLiga/src/com/example/topliga   line 3  Java Problem

The public type Update must be defined in its own file  TopLigaActivity.java    /TopLiga/src/com/example/topliga    line 3  Java Problem

The objective of this code is to check if there is a newer version of this .apk app and, if there is, transfer the new one.

Comment: Well, if the error says that `Update` must be defined in its own file, why don't you create a new file and stick `Update` in there? I don't know what's unclear about that. Alternatively, you can make `Update` non-public, but that may not always work.

Answer (score 0):

You code had a misplaced } in it that made the class finish to soon. This bracket was suposed to be at the very end of you code. So I moved it for you I also moved your imports to the top. And also TopLigaActivity is now a nested class inside Update. If you do not want this you should move it to it's own file so that there's a file named Update and a file named TopLigaActivity. You'll have to do this because you cannot difine two different classes in one file (unless it's a nested class). By the way the bracket I move was the one directly above your imports.
Here is your 'new' code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.example.updater.AutomaticUpdaterActivity;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class Update extends AutomaticUpdaterActivity {
private Object context;

protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    String path = "http://192.168.1.20/android/TopLiga.apk";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("YourApp", "Well that didn't work out so well...");
        Log.e("YourApp", e.getMessage());
    }
    return path;
}

private void publishProgress(int i) {

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String path) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive" );
    Log.d("Lofting", "About to install new .apk");
    ((Activity) this.context).startActivity(i);
}




@SuppressLint("ParserError")
public class TopLigaActivity extends ListActivity {

    static final String URL = "http://minesemhamachi.no-ip.org/android/usersdata.xml";
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "mydata"; // nodo pai
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_username = "Username";
    static final String KEY_password = "Password";

    XMLParser parser;

    @SuppressLint({ "ParserError", "NewApi" })
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                parser = new XMLParser();
                new DownloadXml().execute(URL);
            } 
    }

    private void setListView(String xml) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Obter elemento (DOM)
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); 

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // Iteração sobre todos os nodos <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // Criação de HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // Adição de cada nodo filho ao HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_username, parser.getValue(e, KEY_username));
            map.put(KEY_password, parser.getValue(e, KEY_password));

            // adição da HashList ao ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        // Adição dos menuItems ao ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_username, KEY_password }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.score });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }


    private class DownloadXml extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {           
            return  parser.getXmlFromUrl(urls[0]);            
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            setListView(result);
       }

    }
}
}
```

I hope that this solves your problem.

P.S. you could also make Update a subclass of TopLigaActivity.